# How are Stack Overflow questions stored?

Tags: support, design

I'm wondering How Stack Overflow questions are stored in database, because I want to store long html formatted articles. should I use MySQL database, or it would be better to write them on file using fwrite and store them as files in server side, and give a reference to that file, and use include to get that file. It is not just paragraphs, headings, images ('s), and other containers containing side notes and such. The articles are usually somewhere between 150 000 and 250 000 characters (including spaces), and html tags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions (and answers and tag wiki's) are stored in the posts table in Microsoft SQL Server in the column `body`.

They store the rendered html, as can be seen in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/547654).

The actual field type is `nvarchar (max)` which can hold 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB) but the maximum number of chars per post is capped at 30,000 characters.

In the posthistory table they store the raw markdown for each revision.

If this setup will work in your case depends and you might have to take caching into account (SE use it a lot) but as you can see from the sheer amount of data served here it can work.

You can find more info on MSE in the tag [database-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design) and [architecture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture).

You might also want to read the awesome blogs form [Nick Craver](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/) about the architecture, both software and hardware.